# Angularjs summary row filter

Tags: angularjs, row, angularjs-ng-repeat, summary

I am trying to build a custom filter which would add a summary (avg) row to the array.
I'd like to use it like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | summaryRow : ['col1', 'col1'] | orderBy : 'name'"
```

Here's what my filter looks like:

```
summaryRow.$inject = ['$parse', 'sumFilter'];
function summaryRow($parse, sumFilter) {
    return function(array, fields, nameLabel) {
        var row = { id: 0 }, l = array.length, setter;
        row[nameLabel || 'name'] = 'Summary';
        for (var i = 0, j = fields.length; i < j; i++) {
            setter = $parse(fields[i]).assign;
            setter(row, sumFilter(array, fields[i]) / l);
        }
        return array.concat(row);
    }
}
```

The thing is I want this extra row to be sortable and aware of changes within items. The problem is I'm running into the "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" issue. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$filter` in your controller. Here is a great post written by Todd Motto:

https://toddmotto.com/use-controller-filters-to-prevent-digest-performance-issues/

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, here's what I came up with:

```
summaryRow.$inject = ['$parse', 'sumFilter'];
function summaryRow($parse, sumFilter) {
    var row = {};
    return function(array, fields, nameLabel) {
        clearObject(row);
        var l = array.length, setter;
        row.id = 0;
        row[nameLabel || 'name'] = 'Summary';
        for (var i = 0, j = fields.length; i < j; i++) {
            setter = $parse(fields[i]).assign;
            setter(row, sumFilter(array, fields[i]) / l);
        }
        return array.concat(row);
    }
}
```

And here's the clearObject implementation:

```
function clearObject(obj) {
    for (var k in obj)
        delete obj[k];
}
```

Comment: anyway, take a look at $filter, it is much better in terms of performance.